# Sealed Philadelphia cream cheese left out overnight, is it still safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, cheese

Bought it a the groceries store, and forgot it in the groceries bag.

So it was left at room temperature, in the original **sealed** container for around 12 hours.

Given that cheese should usually be refrigerated, is this product still safe to eat?

Comment: I disagree with duplicate vote. This one is much more specific, and due to these specific conditions answer is almost opposite.

Comment: @Mołot It's really difficult to justify telling people that food that needs refrigeration is OK to eat when left out for hours. Yes, best case they are fine, but worst case, they get very sick. We have that question and close nearly every similar one as a duplicate because we simply can not guarantee food safety if the base guidelines are not followed.

Comment: Not. Specifics don't make any difference. Guidelines are guidelines. We can tell you that we do something different but that doesn't make it safe for you or anyone else. So, still a duplicate as the specifics (brand, etc.) don't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, but depends on brand. More precisely, on manufacturing and packaging processes. If it was subject to some equivalent of pasteurization and is still sealed, probability it spoiled is minimal. If it contains preservatives, it helps. Some brands also have citric acid, and low pH helps to make them a bit shelf stable.

If seal is broken, or if it wasn't pasteurized (or something like that) and does not contain any preservatives, discard it. Otherwise, if it looks good, smells good and tastes good, I'd guess it to be all right, but there is a high chance what I ate was different from your cheese, so no promises. And don't give it to eldry, pregnant or children. You know, better safe than sorry.